# How should I pass the "type" parameter of in a single constructor in an if/else statement?

Tags: java, apex

How should I pass the "type" parameter of a constructor in an if/else statement? For eg - cal(2,2,0,rectangle). So if the type=rectangle then calculate area of a rectangle. If type=circle, calculate the area of a circle.

I am using a single constructor. My issue is that I know the logic but I can't write it in syntax. I am using Java or Apex.

I want to use if-else statement. How should I pass the type parameter in the code?

My program is like this -

1. if "type"=square, the compiler will call calculate area of the square.
2. if "type"=circle, the compiler will call calculate area of the circle.

```
   public class Area {
      
      private String type;
      private Integer length;
      private Integer breadth;
      private Integer height;
      private Integer area;
      
     public void setType(String t){
          type=t;    
      }
      public void setLength(Integer l){
          length=l;    
      }
      public void setbreadth(Integer b){
          breadth=b;    
      }
      public void setheight(Integer h){
          height=h;    
      }
     /* public void setArea(Integer a){
          area=a;    
      } */
  
      public Integer getLength(){
          return length;  
      }
      public Integer getbreadth(){
          return breadth;  
      }
      public Integer getheight(){
          return height;  
      }
      public string gettype(){
          return type;  
      }
      
      public Integer AreaRectangle(){
          return area=length*breadth;
      }
      
      public Integer AreaSquare(){
          return area=length*length;
      }
      
      public integer AreaTriangle(){
          return area=1/2 *(breadth*height);
      }
      
     public Area(){ // default constructor
         length=9;
          breadth=2;
          height=7;       
                  
      }
      public Area(String t,Integer l ,Integer b,Integer h ){         // parameterised constructor
          type=t;
          length=l;
          breadth=b;
          height=h;
                 
      }  
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't. You create an abstract class called shape.

```
public abstract class Shape {
    abstract double area();  
}
```

And then two other classes that extend `Shape` and each provides the proper implementation

```
public class Square extends Shape {
    private int side;
    public Square(int side) {
        this.side = side;
    }
    public double area() {
        return (double) side * side;
    }
}
```

Now at the place you want to call it:

```
Shape shape = new Square(5);
double area = shape.area();

Int radius = 4;
shape = new Circle(radius);
double circle area = shape.area();
```